# Python3 pysal error message for large dataset

Tags: python, pysal

I am using a package called pysal to run the following Theil Decomposition to find within and between outputs.

When I create a small dataframe below the package works.
See code below:

```
import pysal 
path="/Users/username/Desktop/file1.csv"
df_table=pd.read_table(path, sep=",")  
df2=pd.DataFrame(df_table)
df= df2.sort_values(['exposure'], ascending=True)

rr = np.array(df['exposure'])
drop = pysal.inequality.theil.Theil(rr)
print ('drop.T', drop.T) # this is total theil 

dropp = pysal.inequality.theil.TheilD(rr, df['race'] )
print ('WG', dropp.wg) #within group
print ("BG", dropp.bg) #between group
```

When I try to run the same code on a much larger file I get the following ERROR MESSAGE:

How do i fix error message??

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

Below is the sourced code from the pysal package
The data types appear to be the same for both file types.
Im uncertain why it is working work a small file but not a large file.

```
def __init__(self, y, partition):
    groups = np.unique(partition)
    T = Theil(y).T
    ytot = y.sum(axis=0)

    #group totals
    gtot = np.array([y[partition == gid].sum(axis=0) for gid in groups])
    mm = np.dot

    if ytot.size == 1:  # y is 1-d
        sg = gtot / (ytot * 1.)
        sg.shape = (sg.size, 1)
    else:
        sg = mm(gtot, np.diag(1. / ytot))
    ng = np.array([sum(partition == gid) for gid in groups])
    ng.shape = (ng.size,)  # ensure ng is 1-d
    n = y.shape[0]
    # between group inequality
    sg = sg + (sg==0) # handle case when a partition has 0 for sum
    bg = np.multiply(sg, np.log(mm(np.diag(n * 1. / ng), sg))).sum(axis=0)
    self.T = T
    self.bg = bg
    self.wg = T - bg
```

Comment: It seems to work up to row 1,772 in my DataFrame... But not past that